# Transaction keeps failing in solidity

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I have this contract and when I try to fund the contract I keep getting an error:

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted
```

Here is my code:

```
//SPDX-License_Identifier:MIT

pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0;


import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";


contract FundMe{
    using SafeMathChainlink for uint256;


    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    function fund() public payable{
        //50$
        uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10**18;
        require(getConversionRate(msg.value)>= minimumUSD, "You need to spend more ETH");
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        // what ETH -> USD conversion rate
    }


    function getVersion() public view returns(uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
        return priceFeed.version();
    }

    function getPrice()public view returns(uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
        (
            uint80 roundID,
            int price,
            uint startedAt,
            uint timeStamp,
            uint80 answeredInRound
         ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
         return uint256(price * 100000000);
        
    }

    function getConversionRate(uint256 ethAmount)public view returns(uint256){
        uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
        uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethAmount) / 1000000000000000000;
        return ethAmountInUsd;
    }

    function withdraw()payable public{
        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Im using compiler 0.6.0 and I have enough ropsten eth
And when I call the getPrice function I also receive an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted
```

The error is because the transaction you sent failed and reverted. There are multiple reasons that may cause the error, and reasons may include:

- you are using the wrong smart contract address
- the balance of smart contracts is not sufficient
- the params of function are not correct
- cannot pass require statement

In your code, the address of the smart contract you are using for price feed is Rinkeby address, while you are using the Ropsten network.

```
AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
```

Because the oracle smart contract is not deployed in the address, functions wrapped in the interface do not match, and the error happens.

As far as I know, Chainlink products do not support testnet Ropsten, so you can try to change your network to Rinkeby. A list of price feed addresses can be found in [Chainlink's official documents](https://docs.chain.link/docs/ethereum-addresses/).

Comment: You are right dude, thanks, I didnt pay attention to the network

Comment: @Android glad it helps, if it helps, then accept the answer so the answer can help more people.